# mysql "Where not in" using two columns

Tags: mysql

I have one temporary table that contains `userID` and `taskID`. It is called `CompletedTasks`.
I have a second table that contains `userID` and `taskID`. It is called `PlannedTasks`.

I need to get a list of all `taskID`s that were completed, but not planned.
So, I need to somehow weed out from completed tasks, all rows where both:

```
PlannedTasks.userID != CompletedTasks.userID
```

AND

```
PlannedTasks.taskID != CompletedTasks.taskID
```

Comment: I think you need an additional column to indicate status, don't really need two tables.

Comment: @ajreal That is a good point. Perhaps I will consider tweaking the schema in the way you suggested. Appreciate the tip!

Comment: I prefer 2 tables over one table and a status column, 99% of the time. And 11 tables over one table and 10 status columns. It's not easy to optimize a query that searches one or many status columns (in MysQL).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can use this (more compact syntax):

```
SELECT *
FROM CompletedTasks
WHERE (userID, taskID) NOT IN
      ( SELECT userID, taskID
        FROM PlannedTasks
      ) ;
```

or the `NOT EXISTS` version (which although more complex, should be more efficient with proper indexes):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CompletedTasks AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM PlannedTasks AS p
        WHERE p.userID = c.userID
          AND p.taskID = c.taskID
      ) ;
```

and of course the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` version that @jmacinnes has in his answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. I did not know you could use Where on two fields in that way, but was hopeful that that would be an option. Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: Following my tests, the NOT EXISTS version is faster than the NOT_IN version

Comment: @Ka. yes, the `NOT IN` with a tuple is not optimized as good as `NOT EXISTS`. Which version did you test with? I haven't tested if they have improved the optimizer in the new 5.7 version.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need?

```
select ct.* from
completedTasks ct
left outer join plannedTasks pt on ct.taskId = pt.TaskId and ct.userId = pt.userId
where pt.taskId is null
```

However, I agree with the comment - given what we know from the question a status column sounds like a better schema than two tables.

Comment: A status column can be overlooked, not updated, set to the wrong value, etc. A join like this will provide the desired results regardless of the status of the status column.

Answer (score 1):

@ypercubeᵀᴹ  Thanks for sharing below mention query

```
SELECT * FROM CompletedTasks WHERE (userID, taskID) NOT IN
      ( SELECT userID, taskID FROM PlannedTasks) ;'
```

My problem solved.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Actually, I made some change with reference to  @ypercube shared query. Will take care in future. Thanks

Comment: I guess this is the best way. it works fine for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the first answer pretty good, It did work for me, just was missing a ")" after PlannedTasks.
I need to weed out the elements from one table, that were in the other, so...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CompletedTasks
WHERE (userID, taskID) NOT IN
      ( SELECT userID, taskID
        FROM PlannedTasks )
      ) ;
```

---

This is my code:

```
$query_C_Ranking = sprintf("SELECT * 
                                FROM tblpinturas
                                WHERE (idCode) NOT IN 
                                        (SELECT idCode FROM tblranking)
                                ");
```

Comment: For the SO platform to work correctly, existing Answers should be upvoted, not duplicated. If there is a typo, either add Comment below the post, or suggest. The SO platform operates in a different way than forums do. But that is part of the value of this platform. Each platform has is strengths. Also, when referencing another post (Q or A), it needs to be linked to, as there is no other easy way to tell which post you're referring to. The order of Answers changes, as the number of Answers, and votes for each changes. It also depends on the "sort" order each user has chosen.