# MySQL: Select from table A which does not exist in table B

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compose a SELECT statement for MySQL which select from table A what does not exist in table B. Most of examples use only one field as key. In my case, I have 3 fields.

```
TableA => a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,1
1,5,1

TableB => b.fieldA, b.fieldB, b.fieldC
1,1,1
1,3,1
1,4,1
```

So I only want the fields from TableA that does not exist in TableB

```
Result
1,2,1
1,5,1
```

I tried LEFT JOIN, but have no luck

```
SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
FROM TableA a 

LEFT JOIN TableB b ON (
a.fieldA = b.fieldA 
AND a.fieldB = b.fieldB 
AND a.fieldC = b.fieldC) 

WHERE a.fieldA = 1 
AND a.fieldC = 1
```

I also tried NOT IN, but didn't know how to do that with 3 fields.

I know this must be simple, but I am blind. bad day :(

Comment: You are almost there.. Just add `AND b.fieldA IS NULL` to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Using NOT IN :**

```
SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
FROM tableA a 
WHERE (a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC) NOT IN (
SELECT b.fieldA, b.fieldB, b.fieldC
FROM  tableB b)
```

**Using LEFT JOIN :**

```
SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
FROM tableA a 

LEFT JOIN tableB b ON (
a.fieldA = b.fieldA 
AND a.fieldB = b.fieldB 
AND a.fieldC = b.fieldC) 

WHERE b.fieldA IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

I just Find out in a similar quetion [another way using **NOT EXISTS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8435149/5671807)

```
SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
FROM tableA a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM  tableB b 
WHERE a.fieldA = b.fieldA 
AND a.fieldB = b.fieldB 
AND a.fieldC = b.fieldC
);
```

Comment: NOT IN was like clear water for me, works perfect and I understand it perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PatricioCarvajalH. Glad it helps, You are so welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concat fields and then compare them all at once

```
SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
FROM TableA a 
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON (
    CONCAT(a.fieldA,a.fieldB,a.fieldC) <> CONCAT(b.fieldA,b.fieldB,b.fieldC)
)
```

Comment: This is almost a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it works:

```
select * from TableA where (fieldA,fieldB,fieldC) not in (select * from TableB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the left join the column of the left related  table that don't match  return null  values  so just filter   left table columns where is null

```
  SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
  FROM TableA a 
  LEFT JOIN TableB b ON 
    a.fieldA = b.fieldA 
      AND a.fieldB = b.fieldB 
        AND a.fieldC = b.fieldC
  WHERE a.fieldA = 1 
  AND a.fieldC = 1
  AND ( b.fieldC is null  OR b.fieldA is null OR a.fieldB is null)
```

or you can use NOT IN  for same condition

```
  SELECT a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC
  FROM TableA a 
  WHERE a.fieldA = 1 
  AND a.fieldC = 1
  AND (a.fieldA, a.fieldB, a.fieldC) NOT IN (
    SELECT b.fieldA, b.fieldB, b.fieldC
    FROM TableB b
    WHERE b.fieldA = 1 
    AND b.fieldC = 1
  )
```